# How to prove or disprove that a complete sufficient statistic exists?

Tags: sufficient-statistics, complete-statistics, indicator-function, discrete-distributions

We have a discrete random variable which takes values with probabilities $p, q, p+q$ and $r$. I want to construct a complete sufficient statistic based on a single observation from this distribution, or disprove its existence.

First of all, I thought that no complete statistic exists, since if $T(X)$ is a statistic and $E(g(T(X)))\equiv0$, it just implies a relationship between the values taken by $g$ at the support of $X$. In particular, if the values taken by $X$ are $1,2,3$ and $4$, then, this implies
$$pg(1)+qg(2)+(p+q)g(3)-2(p+q)g(4)=0$$
and we can easily construct $g$ which is not identically zero but this holds.

But then I realised that $\mathbb I_{[X=4]}$ is complete, but not sufficient. This is because expectation of any function $g$ of this statistic is $rg(1)+(1-r)g(0)$ and therefore $g(1)=g(0)=0$ if this expectation is zero for all $r\in (0,1)$.

Question is

> 1. How do I find a complete sufficient statistic or disprove its existence?
> 2. Where was my reasoning wrong, that no complete statistic exists?